# Use Random.random [30,35] to print random numbers between 30,35. Seed(70)

Tags: python, random, multiplication, random-seed

Probably a simple answer, not sure what I am missing. For a homework assignment I have to use `random.random()` to generate numbers between 30 and 35. The seed has to be set to `70` to match the pseudo-random numbers with the grader. This wasn't in my lecture so I am a little stumped as to what to do.

I have:

```
import random 
def problem2_4():
    print(random.random(30,35))
```

But this is clearly wrong.

The assignment says the output should look like (note: for the problem i use `def problem2_4()` just for the assignment grading system)

```
problem2_4()
[34.54884618961936, 31.470395203793395, 32.297169396656095, 30.681793552717807,
 34.97530360173135, 30.773219981037737, 33.36969776732032, 32.990127772708405, 
 33.57311858494461, 32.052629620057274]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output `[blah, blah, blah]` indicates that it is a *list* of numbers rather than a series of numbers printed one-by-one.

In addition, if you want random floating point values, you'll need to transform the numbers from `random.random` (which are zero to one) into that range.

That means you'll probably need something like:

```
import random                                # Need this module.
def problem2_4():
    random.seed(70)                          # Set initial seed.
    nums = []                                # Start with empty list.
    for _ in range(10):                      # Will add ten values.
        nums += [random.random() * 5 + 30]   # Add one value in desired range.
    print(nums)                              # Print resultant list.
```

Of course, the *Pythonic* way to do this would be:

```
import random
random.seed(70)
print([random.random() * 5 + 30 for _ in range(10)])
```

Bit that might be a bit ahead of where your educator is working. Still, it's good to learn this stuff as early as possile since you'll never be a Pythonista until you do :-)

Answer (score -1):

The function that you are looking for is `randint`, which returns an integer (whole number) between the specified minimum and maximum values.

So the solution would be

```
random.randint(30, 35)
```

[Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)

Comment: Since the sample output contains decimal places, this is clearly wrong.